# Oracle REGEXP_REPLACE on CLOB 12c

Tags: oracle, regexp-replace

This is really strange.  I run the following query on an 11g database, and the results are what I expect:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(json_content, '<acronym class=\\\"ticker\\\">([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5})</acronym>','<a href=\"https://www.example.com/stock/quote/\1\">\1</a>'),json_content 
FROM message_lobs
WHERE revision_id = 211576;
```

Works fine and gives proper output.   But, if I run this in 12c, I get this as output:

```
"<CONNECTION><VERSIONSTRING>Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production</VERSIONSTRING><RELEASE>12.2.0.1.0</RELEASE><USERNAME>SYSTEM</USERNAME><SERVICENAME>VOLGA.EXAMPLE.COM</SERVICENAME></CONNECTION>"
```

And actually, in some cases, unprintable characters:

```
᫔᦬᨜Ŏ}᭄#ਜᩔ᪂᪴ᨖ᪄ᨠ᪐ᩢଊᬾ;᫘Ѽ᩼Fь
```

I am doing this query in the Toad Editor.  Note this is a CLOB column.  Anyone now why this would be?  It almost seems like something is not compatible, or has changed in 12c?

Comment: Is your clob in the 12c database in good shape? I mean, are the strange characters there without running regexp_replace?